# WPF Prism 6 View Model created more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm relatively new to Prism 6, and have looked at other stackoverflow postings to try and get an answer to my issue. I have a view module constructor that gets executed every time I navigate to the page.

In the bootstrap file, ConfigureContainer function, I have the following declaration:

```
base.ConfigureContainer();

//Container.RegisterInstance<JobList>(new JobList());
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<JobList>("JobList");
```

Using the Container.RegisterInstance function for JobList seems to make no difference.

The top of the JobList view looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="JobListModule.Views.JobList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Width="1090" Height="900"
>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"/>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="830*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Row="0" OpacityMask="#FFEEEBEB" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="83*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="JobListLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.JobListBuildListLabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="613" FontSize="48" Margin="67,-2,74,2" Height="70" RenderTransformOrigin="1.695,0.222" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddJobFileBtn" Command="{Binding AddJobBtnClickedCommand}" Grid.Column="1" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.JobListAddBuildFileBtnText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="56,10,64,11" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="216" Height="49" RenderTransformOrigin="0.203,-0.173" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBEC9CF"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5EB4C7" Offset="0.936"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC9E9F0" Offset="0.319"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="BuildList" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=JobFileInfoList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=JobListSelectedItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="114*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="750"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="JobFileNameLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding JobFileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0"/>
                    <dx:SimpleButton Command="{Binding DataContext.LoadJobBtnClickedCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding JobFileName}" Grid.Column="1" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.JobListPrintBtnLabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,19,23,25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="60" RenderTransformOrigin="0.203,-0.173" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0"/>
                    <dx:SimpleButton Command="{Binding DataContext.TrashCanBtnClickedCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding JobFileName}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="86" Height="86" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <Image Source="..\ButtonImages\TrashCan-64.png" />
                    </dx:SimpleButton>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the JobList.xaml.cs file contains:

```
public partial class JobList
{
    public JobList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The JobList View Model is as follows:

```
using Common.GatedEvents;
using CommonApp;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Regions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using VulcanGUI.Services;
using VulcanGUI.Logging;
using VulcanGUI.DialogService;
using VulcanGUI.DialogService.ViewModels;

namespace VulcanGUI.JobListModule.ViewModels
{
public class JobListViewModel : BindableBase, IDescribe, IInteractionRequestAware, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly log4net.ILog _logger;
    protected readonly IEventAggregator EventAggregator;

    // Delete Job Queue AMX File Confirmation
    public InteractionRequest<IConfirmation> ConfirmationRequest { get; private set; }
    public InteractionRequest<INotification> ErrorNotification { get; private set; }

    private bool _deleteJobConfirmationRequestResult;
    private bool _printJobConfirmationRequestResult;
    public DelegateCommand RaiseDeleteJobConfirmationCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand RaiseLoadJobConfirmationCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand LoadJobErrorNotificationCommand { get; private set; }

    private readonly IDialogService _openFileDialogService;
    private readonly IJobListDataService _jobListDataService;

    private string JobFilePath {get; set;}

    public int JobListSelectedItemIndex { get; set; }

    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<JobFileInfoItem> _jobFileInfoList;

    public ObservableCollection<JobFileInfoItem> JobFileInfoList
    {
        get { return _jobFileInfoList; }
        set { _jobFileInfoList = value; }
    }

    public JobListViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager,
                            ILog4NetLogger logger, 
                            IDialogService openFileDialogSvc, 
                            IJobListDataService jobListDataSvc,
                            IEventAggregator eventAggregator
                           )
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        EventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        ConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();
        ErrorNotification = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
        RaiseDeleteJobConfirmationCommand = new DelegateCommand(RaiseDeleteJobFromListConfirmation);
        RaiseLoadJobConfirmationCommand = new DelegateCommand(RaiseLoadJobConfirmation);
        LoadJobErrorNotificationCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadJobErrorNotification);
        _openFileDialogService = openFileDialogSvc;
        _jobListDataService = jobListDataSvc;
        _logger = logger.GetLog4NetLogger();

        AppEvents.MachineStatus.Event += MachineStatusHandler;
        AppEvents.JobFileReady.Event += JobFileReadyHandler;

        LoadJobFileInfoList();
    }

    public JobListViewModel() { }

    public string Describe(string preface = "")
    {
        return preface + " JobListViewModel";
    }

    public log4net.ILog log
    {
        get { return _logger; }
    }

    private void LoadJobErrorNotification(object errMsg)
    {
        //var vm = new ErrorDialogViewModel((string)errMsg);
        var vm = new ErrorDialogViewModel() {Message = (string) errMsg};
        var result = DialogService.DialogService.OpenDialog(vm);
    }

    protected void JobFileReadyHandler(Object sender, GatedEventBase thisEvent, JobReadyArgs args)
    {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => LoadJobErrorNotification(args.Error));
        if (args.Error.Length != 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ViewsRegion", "BuildActivity", new NavigationParameters("Test")));
        }
    }

    protected void MachineStatusHandler(Object sender, GatedEventBase thisEvent, MachineStatusArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Request)
        {
            //CommonEvents.Processor.AddTask(new TaskEvent(this, AppEvents.MachineStatus, new MachineStatusArgs(OperationState)));
        }
    }

    private void LoadJobFileInfoList()
    {
        var jobFileInfoList = _jobListDataService.GetJobListFilePathData();

        _jobFileInfoList = new ObservableCollection<JobFileInfoItem>();

        foreach (string jobFile in jobFileInfoList)
        {
            _jobFileInfoList.Add(new JobFileInfoItem(jobFile));
        }
    }

    #region AddJobToList
    public ICommand AddJobBtnClickedCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(AddJobBtnClickedMethod); }
        //get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(LoadJobBtnClickedMethod, CanLoadJobBtnClickedMethodBeExecuted); }
    }

    private void AddJobBtnClickedMethod()
    {
        ShowOpenFileDialog();
    }

    public void ShowOpenFileDialog()
    {
        var settings = new OpenFileDialogSettings()
        {
            Title = "Select Job File",
            InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
            Filter = "Build File ( *.amx; *.txt) |*.amx; *.txt"
        };

        if (_openFileDialogService.ShowOpenFileDialog(settings))
        {
            JobFilePath = settings.FileName;
            // Does the JobFilePath already exist in the list?
            if (_jobFileInfoList.Any(p => p.JobFileFullPath == JobFilePath))
            {
                // Since the path is already in the list, just show it as selected
                JobListSelectedItemIndex = _jobFileInfoList.FindIndex(p => p.JobFileFullPath == JobFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add it to the list
                _jobFileInfoList.Add(new JobFileInfoItem(JobFilePath));

                //Persist the list items
                List<string> jobFilePathInfo = JobInfoObsListToList();
                _jobListDataService.SaveJobListFilePathData(jobFilePathInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion AddJobToList

    #region DeleteJobFromList
    private void RaiseDeleteJobFromListConfirmation()
    {
        // By invoking the Raise method we are raising the Raised event and triggering any InteractionRequestTrigger that
        // is subscribed to it.
        // As parameters we are passing a Confirmation, which is a default implementation of IConfirmation (which inherits
        // from INotification) provided by Prism and a callback that is executed when the interaction finishes.
        ConfirmationRequest.Raise(
            new Confirmation { Content = "Remove this build file from the list?", Title = "Confirmation" },
            c => { _deleteJobConfirmationRequestResult = c.Confirmed; });
    }

    public ICommand TrashCanBtnClickedCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(TrashCanBtnClickedMethod); }
    }

    private void TrashCanBtnClickedMethod(Object jobFileName)
    {
        RaiseDeleteJobFromListConfirmation();

        if ( _deleteJobConfirmationRequestResult )
        {
            // Determine the index of the _jobFileInfoList item containing the filename
            var listIndex = _jobFileInfoList.FindIndex(p => p.JobFileName == (string)jobFileName);
            _jobFileInfoList.RemoveAt(listIndex);
            var jobFilePathInfo = JobInfoObsListToList();
            _jobListDataService.SaveJobListFilePathData(jobFilePathInfo);
        }
    }

    List<string> JobInfoObsListToList()
    {
        var jobFilePaths = new List<string>();

        foreach( JobFileInfoItem jobInfo in _jobFileInfoList )
        {
            jobFilePaths.Add(jobInfo.JobFileFullPath);
        }

        return jobFilePaths;
    }

    #endregion DeleteJobFromList

    #region LoadJob
    public ICommand LoadJobBtnClickedCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(LoadJobBtnClickedMethod); }
    }

    private void RaiseLoadJobConfirmation()
    {
        // By invoking the Raise method we are raising the Raised event and triggering any InteractionRequestTrigger that
        // is subscribed to it.
        // As parameters we are passing a Confirmation, which is a default implementation of IConfirmation (which inherits
        // from INotification) provided by Prism and a callback that is executed when the interaction finishes.
        ConfirmationRequest.Raise(
            new Confirmation { Content = "Load this job file?", Title = "Confirmation" },
            c => { _printJobConfirmationRequestResult = c.Confirmed; });
    }

    private void LoadJobBtnClickedMethod(Object jobFileName)
    {
        RaiseLoadJobConfirmation();

        if (_printJobConfirmationRequestResult)
        {
            int listIndex = _jobFileInfoList.FindIndex(p => p.JobFileName == (string)jobFileName);

            string jobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var args = new String2Args(jobId, _jobFileInfoList[listIndex].JobFileFullPath);
            var s = Path.GetExtension(_jobFileInfoList[listIndex].JobFileFullPath);
            if (s != null)
            {
                string extension = s.ToLower();
                if (extension == ".txt")
                    CommonEvents.Processor.AddTask(new TaskEvent(this, AppEvents.TextDataFile, args));
                else
                    CommonEvents.Processor.AddTask(new TaskEvent(this, AppEvents.AMXBuildFile, args));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion LoadJob
    //private bool CanLoadJobBtnClickedMethodBeExecuted(object context)
    //{
    //    //this is called to evaluate whether FuncToCall can be called
    //    //for example you can return true or false based on some validation logic
    //    return true;
    //}


    public INotification Notification { get; set; }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        navigationContext.Parameters.Add("PageFrom", ToString());
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is no need to register an instance of `JobList` with the container if you are using `RegisterTypeForNavigation`.

Comment: Thank you for your observation ... I removed the RegisterInstance call in the bootstrap.cs file, but the constructor for the JobList View Model still gets called every time I navigate to it.

Comment: Can you add your `JobList` view model code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `INavigationAware` interface, and `IsNavigationTarget` is always returning false. That is what is causing this.

Either change this to return true or false based on some logic, or have it return true all the time. Or, remove the use of the `INavigationAware` entirely if it really isn't needed.

If a view, or view model, implements the `INavigationAware` interface the `IsNavigationTarget` function is called during navigation. If the returns true, it uses an existing instance of the view or view model, if one exists. Otherwise, it creates a new instance.

You can use the `NavigationContext` passed into the function to do stuff like check the `Parameters` collection values, or what not, and based on those values, either use an existing instance by returning true, or have the app create a new instance of the view/view model by returning false.

Comment: OMG!! Never would have guessed that INavigationAware would cause this type of behavior.  Mr. Richards, thank you SO MUCH !!!

Comment: Any time, my friend. Glad to help!

Comment: Just curious ... why would using INavigationAware cause a new instance of the view model to be created every time the view is navigated to?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer for you on that.

Comment: "If the IsNavigationTarget method always returns true, regardless of the navigation parameters, that view instance will always be re-used. This allows you to ensure that only one view of a particular type will be displayed in a particular region."    .... AWESOME!! Thanks again!!